# grails UrlMapping for version-specific API controllers

Tags: spring, grails

I'm building a versioned API on grails 3.1.6 platform, here's what I have:

```
package mysearch
```

class UrlMappings {

```
static mappings = {
    for(controller in grails.util.Holders.getGrailsApplication().controllerClasses) {
        def cName = controller.logicalPropertyName
        if(cName.endsWith('API')) {
            def controllerName = cName.replace('API', '').replaceAll(/V(\d{1})/, '')
            "/api/$version/${controllerName}/$action"(controller: controllerName + version + "API", action: action, parseRequest: true)
        }
    }

    "500"(view:'/error')
    "404"(view:'/notFound')
}
```

}

When I try submitting a request with Postman though, I'm getting 404.
Upon investigation, I can see that `UrlMappingInfo` instance created(matched) as part of request mapping has this format: "/api/(*)/merchant/(*)" 
which seems OK provided the values would be replaced with the appropriate param values, eg. /api/V1/merchant/find for this Postman request
http://localhost:9090/api/V1/merchant/find
But they are not resolved and obviously Grails cannot find controller in its `mappingsToGrailsControllerMap`
When I debug the request and replace the UrlMappingInfo with the "correct" values, the request is correctly handled by my controller. What am I missing? Possibly syntax in UrlMapping controller: area? Tried with and without $ in front of variable name but no luck. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be not so easy as mappings are evaluated once, and the version parameter is not "expanded" into controller name.